# free drawn lines with borders, is that possible?

Tags: line-art

I try to construct my own boardgame and maps..

Therefor im looking for a good..no, great and 'easy to use' way to draw curved/ free drawn lines with borders. I would like to choose colors on both line/borders and vary thickness. Is this possible? 
Haven't found anything so far, so all help is more than welcome!
Cheers!:D

Comment: Have you looked into Illustrator?

Comment: Almost **any** graphic application can draw lines and change colors. Doesn't seem like you've done *any* looking whatsoever, or you aren't describing what you need well enough.

Comment: @Scott Perhaps he's talking more so about custom brushes?

Comment: Microsoft Paint can do that. If you want vectorized results you can look at Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Hum... In reality I do understand what the user is asking. I am voting to re open it. user287001 also is posting one option.

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape (=freeware) has several tools for this

- stroke to path (=convert a curve to fillable area which can have a new outline stroke)
- offset path (=a copy with some selectable distance)
- path function "pattern along path" (arbitary shape follows a separately drawn curve)
- bending a shape from clipboard along a curve as you draw it

The first option is the simplest. But the curve loses its editability as a curve, so you need a spare copy which is not converted.

The last option is demonstrated here:

[image]

1. Three lines are drawn and aligned
2. The middle line has got a blue, much wider stroke and the pattern is grouped & copied to the clipboard
3. Three different curves has been drawn with freeform curve tool and the pen. All have option "Bend from clipboard" ON.